# RSpec says 'undefined method' when running against module that includes another module

Tags: ruby, rspec

my situation is the current:

```
module Base
 module A
  include Base::B
 end
end

module Base
 module B
  module_function
  def my_method
   ...
  end
 end
end
```

And then my test:

```
Rspec.describe Base::A do
 describe '.my_method' do
  it 'does something'
   ...
  end
 end
end
```

Problem:

> NoMethodError. undefined method `my_method' for Base::A:Module

What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
module Base
  module B
    module_function

    def my_method
      "you've found me!"
    end
  end
end

module Base
  module A
    include Base::B
  end
end
```

`module_function` lets us call our method on the module by defining a singleton method (a full separate copy of *my_method*):

```
>> Base::B.singleton_methods
=> [:my_method]
>> Base::B.my_method
=> "you've found me!"
```

It also turns `my_method` into a private method, this is the method you get when "including" or "extending":

```
>> Base::B.private_instance_methods
=> [:my_method]

# NOTE: we can call this version of `my_method` by including or 
#       extending the module in a class.
#       using `send` to call private methods outside the class.

class Included
  include Base::B
end

>> Included.private_instance_methods
=> [:my_method, ...]
>> Included.new.send(:my_method)
=> "you've found me!"

class Extended
  extend Base::B
end

# this would be a private class method
>> Extended.private_methods
=>[:my_method, ...]
>> Extended.send(:my_method)
=> "you've found me!"

# NOTE: very simple rules to keep in mind
#
#   instance method => include => instance method
#   instance method => extend  => method
```

Same rules apply if `Base::B` is included in `Base::A` module:

```
>> Base::B.private_instance_methods
=> [:my_method]

# NOTE: we cannot call `my_method` on the module, because we do not get a 
#       singleton method (or private method)
>> Base::A.singleton_methods
=> []

# there is the expected instance method, made private by using `module_function`
>> Base::A.private_instance_methods
=> [:my_method]

# only we can't call `.new` on a module.
>> Base::A.new.send(:my_method)
`<main>': undefined method `new' ...
```

Since we can't initialize an instance out of the module, we can bump the instance method to a class method by extending `Base::A` with `self`.

```
module Base
  module A
    include Base::B
    extend self # extend Base::A, add instance methods to (class) methods
  end
end

>> Base::A.private_methods
=> [:my_method, ...]
>> Base::A.send(:my_method)
=> "you've found me!"
```

or extend `Base::B` from the start:

```
module Base
  module A
    extend Base::B
  end
end

>> Base::A.send(:my_method)
=> "you've found me!"
```

---

`module_function` does the equivalent of this:

```
module Base
  module C
    # NOTE: singleton method stays in this module
    def self.my_method
      "singleton my_method"
    end
    
    private

    # NOTE: instance method gets included/extended
    def my_method
      "private instance my_method"
    end
  end
end

Base::C.my_method                               # => "singleton my_method"
Class.new.extend(Base::C).send(:my_method)      # => "private instance my_method"
Class.new.include(Base::C).new.send(:my_method) # => "private instance my_method"
Module.new.extend(Base::C).send(:my_method)     # => "private instance my_method"
Module.new.include(Base::C).send(:my_method)    # => undefined method
Module.new{extend self}.include(Base::C).send(:my_method)
                                                # => "private instance my_method"
```

---

*https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Module.html#method-i-module_function*

*https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Module.html#method-i-include*

*https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Object.html#method-i-extend*

Comment: hands down to this great explanation, it didn't only make me understand properly what **module_function** does, but it explained me simply the difference between **extend** and **include** while out there there is a sea of complex words that are far from a simple and clear explanation as this. Thank you very much!